Evaluate $\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}{x^2-6x+5}\mathrm dx$

Evaluate the following integral:
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}{x^2-6x+5}\mathrm dx$$

Context: In my differential equations class, one of the questions we were given involved the integral
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2}\mathrm dx$$
My teacher solved it by rationalizing the numerator:
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x^2}\mathrm dx$$
$$=\int\frac{x^2+1}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}}\mathrm dx$$
$$=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}+\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
Now, it becomes doable. While going through this question, I started pondering about integrals of the type $\int\frac{\sqrt{Q_1}}{Q_2}\mathrm dx$ where $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are quadratic functions in $x$. Hence, I took an example of such a form and thought of posting it on this site along with my approach.

Kindly note that this is a self-answered post. Your comments and alternative methods are highly appreciated.

You could try letting $x = \frac{4u}{1-u^2}-1$, which leads to some nasty partial fraction decomposition and finding the antiderivative of some nicer rational expressions.

I have added context in my question, please tell me what other details I need to add(since this question has received a close vote for this reason).

People vote to close posts for all kinds of reasons. Don't worry about it. What matters is that you show you're willing to put in the work and learn, which I can tell is true based on your answer below.

I agree with the comment of @Accelerator.  While your question is somewhat off the beaten track, and your question is not that well composed (i.e. you didn't state up front that it was a self-answer question, where you were inviting other approaches) I personally feel that your posting is a high quality question, specifically because you provided your own answer.

@Accelerator I got to $$2\text{sgn}(u^2-1)\int\frac{(u^2+1)^2}{(u^2-1)(u^2+2u-1)(3u^2+2u-3)}\mathrm du$$ from your substitution. Is partial fractions the only way to carry this further?!

It seems to be the most efficient way based on what you have in the denominator. Is there a different method you have in mind?

@Accelerator I don’t think so there is another method. The denominator looks really messy.

Correct. After partial fractions the first time, you should get four rational expressions: two of which you can do partial fractions again and the other two where they have an easy antiderivative.

In general, assume $Q_1=x^2+b_1 x+c$ and $Q_2=x^2+b_2 x+c$. Then, the integral $\displaystyle\int\frac{\sqrt{Q_1}}{Q_2}\mathrm dx$ can be decomposed as
$$
 \int\frac{\sqrt{Q_1}}{Q_2}\mathrm dx=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{Q_1}}
 + \int \frac{\mathrm dt_+ }{t_+^2- \frac{b_2-2\sqrt c}{b_2-b_1}}
 + \int \frac{\mathrm dt_- }{t_-^2 - \frac{b_2+2\sqrt c}{b_2-b_1}}
$$
where the pair of the substituted variables are $\displaystyle t_\pm = \frac{x\pm \sqrt c}{\sqrt{Q_1}}$. So, the given example has the solution
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}{x^2-6x+5}\mathrm dx
= \tanh^{-1}\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}\\
\hspace{15mm}-\frac {\sqrt2}{\phi}\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt2(x+\sqrt5)}
{\phi \sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}
-{\sqrt2}\phi\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt2\phi(x-\sqrt5)}
{\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}+C\\
$$

Wonderful solution! How did you come up with the idea to perform such a substitution?

Also, is there any simple way to verify this substitution? I did it by using the quotient rule for expressing $\mathrm dt_\pm$ in terms of $\mathrm dx$, it was quite messy but in the end, the term $\pm2\sqrt c-b_1$ cancelled out.

Also, the appearance of the Golden ratio here is quite amusing!

And, is there a way to directly write $\displaystyle\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}=\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}\right)+C$ without going through the $\sinh^{-1}$ as an intermediate step? I am asking this as I have seen this in some of your answers.

Say
$$\mathcal I=\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}{x^2-6x+5}\mathrm dx$$
$$=\int\frac{x^2+2x+5}{(x-1)(x-5)\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}\mathrm dx$$
Now, rewrite $x^2+2x+5$ as:
$$x^2+2x+5=A(x^2-6x+5)+B(x-1)+C(x-5)$$
$$\implies A=1, B=10, C=-2$$
So,
$$\mathcal I=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+4}}+10\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{(x-5)\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}-2\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}$$
Say
$$\mathcal I_1=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{(x-5)\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}\text{ and }\mathcal I_2=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{(x-1)\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}$$
then
$$\mathcal I=\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}2\right)+10\mathcal I_1-2\mathcal I_2$$
Substitute $x-5=\frac1{t}$ in $\mathcal I_1$ and $x-1=\frac1{t}$ in $\mathcal I_2$:
$$\mathcal I_1=-\text{sgn}t\int\frac{\mathrm dt}{|t|\sqrt{\left(5+\frac1{t}\right)^2+2\left(5+\frac1{t}\right)+5}}$$
$$=\frac{-\text{sgn}t}{2\sqrt{10}}\int\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{\left(t+\frac3{20}\right)+\left(\frac1{20}\right)^2}}$$
$$=\frac{-\text{sgn}t}{2\sqrt{10}}\sinh^{-1}(20t+3)+C$$
$$=\frac{\text{sgn}(5-x)}{2\sqrt{10}}\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{20}{x-5}+3\right)+C$$
$$\mathcal I_2=-\text{sgn}t\int\frac{\mathrm dt}{|t|\sqrt{\left(1+\frac1{t}\right)^2+2\left(1+\frac1{t}\right)+5}}$$
$$=\frac{-\text{sgn}t}{2\sqrt2}\int\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{\left(t+\frac14\right)+\left(\frac14\right)^2}}$$
$$=\frac{-\text{sgn}t}{2\sqrt2}\sinh^{-1}(4t+1)+C$$
$$=\frac{\text{sgn}(1-x)}{2\sqrt2}\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac4{x-1}+1\right)+C$$
$$\therefore\boxed{\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+5}}{x^2-6x+5}\mathrm dx=\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1}2\right)+\frac{\sqrt{10}\text{sgn}(5-x)}{2}\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{20}{x-5}+3\right)+\frac{\text{sgn}(x-1)}{\sqrt2}\sinh^{-1}\left(\frac4{x-1}+1\right)+C}$$

$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2 x+5}}{x^2-6 x+5} d x=\frac{1}{4} \int\left[\frac{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+4}}{x-5} d x-\int \frac{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+4}}{x-1} d x\right]=\frac{1}{4}(I_5-I_1),
$$
where $$
\begin{aligned}
I_k & =\int \frac{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+4}}{x-k} d x\\&=\int \frac{2 \cosh \theta}{\sinh \theta-k} \cdot 2 \cosh \theta d \theta, \quad \textrm{ where }x+1=2\sinh \theta \\
& =4 \int \frac{\sinh ^2 \theta-k^2+k^2+1}{\sinh \theta-k} d \theta \\
& =4 \int(\sinh \theta+k) d \theta+4\left(k^2+1\right) \int \frac{1}{\sinh \theta-k} d \theta\\&=4(\cosh \theta+k\theta+(k^2+1)J_k)
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
J_k & =\int \frac{1}{\frac{e^\theta-e^{-\theta}}{2}-k} d \theta \\
& =2 \int \frac{1}{e^\theta-e^{-\theta}-2 k} d \theta \\
& =2 \int \frac{e^\theta}{e^{2 \theta}-2 k e^\theta-1} d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}} \int\left(\frac{e^\theta}{e^\theta-\alpha}-\frac{e^\theta}{e-\beta}\right) d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}} \ln \left| \frac{e^\theta-\alpha}{e^\theta-\beta} \right |+C \\
& =\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}} \ln \left| \frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(x+1+\sqrt{x^2+2 x+5}\right)-\alpha}{\frac{1}{2}\left(x+1+\sqrt{x^2+2 x+5}\right)-\beta} \right |+C
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\alpha=k+\sqrt{k^2+1}$ and $\beta=k-\sqrt{k^2+1}.$
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2 x+5}}{x^2-6 x+5} d x \\= & \frac{1}{4}\left(I_5-I_1\right) \\
= & \frac{1}{4} \left[ 4 \sinh ^{-1} \frac{x+1}{2}+\sqrt{26} \ln \left|\frac{x-9 -2\sqrt{26} +\sqrt{x^2+2 x+5}}{x-9 +2\sqrt{26} +\sqrt{x^2+2 x+5}}\right| -\sqrt{2} \ln \left|\frac{x-1-2\sqrt 2+\sqrt{x^2+2 x+5}}{x-1+2\sqrt 2+\sqrt{x^2+2 x+5}}\right|\right]+C
\end{aligned}
$$

It’s wrong. The result does not recover integrand after differentiation

$$
\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2 x+5}}{x^2-6 x+5} d x=\frac{1}{4} \int\left[\frac{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+4}}{x-5} d x-\int \frac{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+4}}{x-1} d x\right]=\frac{1}{4}(I_5-I_1),
$$
where $$
\begin{aligned}
I_k & =\int \frac{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+4}}{x-k} d x\\&=\int \frac{2 \cosh \theta}{\sinh \theta-k} \cdot 2 \cosh \theta d \theta, \quad \textrm{ where }x+1=2\sinh \theta \\
& =4 \int \frac{\sinh ^2 \theta-k^2+k^2+1}{\sinh \theta-k} d \theta \\
& =4 \int(\sinh \theta+k) d \theta+4\left(k^2+1\right) \int \frac{1}{\sinh \theta-k} d \theta\\&=4(\cosh \theta+k\theta+(k^2+1)J_k)
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
J_k & =\int \frac{1}{\frac{e^\theta-e^{-\theta}}{2}-k} d \theta \\
& =2 \int \frac{1}{e^\theta-e^{-\theta}-2 k} d \theta \\
& =2 \int \frac{e^\theta}{e^{2 \theta}-2 k e^\theta-1} d \theta \\& =2\int \frac{e^\theta}{\left(e^\theta-k\right)^2-(k^2+1)} d \theta \\ & =-\frac{2}{\sqrt{k^2+1}} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{e^\theta-k}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}\right) \\ & =-\frac{2}{\sqrt{k^2+1}} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\cosh \theta+\sinh \theta-k}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}\right) \\ & =-\frac{2}{\sqrt{k^2+1}} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2 x+5}+x+1-2 k}{2 \sqrt{k^2+1}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2 x+5}}{x^2-6 x+5} d x \\= & \frac{1}{4}\left(I_5-I_1\right) \\
\\=&\frac{1}{2}\left[2 \sinh ^{-1} \frac{x+1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{26}} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2 x+5}+x-9}{2 \sqrt{26}}\right)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2 x+5}+x-1}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)\right]+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Another method is to use the tangent half-angle substitution.

Another way to evaluate $\mathcal I_1$ and $\mathcal I_2$ in my previous answer is to perform the hyperbolic substitution $x+1=2\sinh t$:
$$\mathcal I_1=\int\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sinh t-3}$$
$$=2\int\frac{e^t\mathrm dt}{(e^{2t}-6e^t+9)-10}$$
Now, just substitute $e^t-3=u$ and then back substitute for $u$.
Similarly,
$$\mathcal I_2=\int\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sinh t-1}$$
$$=2\int\frac{e^t\mathrm dt}{(e^{2t}-2e^t+1)-2}$$
Now, it is obvious to put $e^t-1=u$ and then back substitute for $u$.
